# How to see if password matches in arraylist of objects

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I am trying to see if the password that was user inputted in method addUser() matches the password user inputted in the method deleteUser(). Both methods look into the users arraylist that is full of FacebookUser objects, However, I cannot figure out how to match the appropriate passwords from each method.

I have tried multiple codes I can hardly even remember, sometimes I'd always get "incorrect password" returned even when it is correct But whenever I had only one object in my arraylist it would work until I added another user. It would make both users end up with the same password.

```
public class Facebook extends FacebookUser implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    private ArrayList<FacebookUser> users;

    public Facebook(String username, String password) {
        super(username, password);
        users = new ArrayList<>();

    }

    // prints users
    public void listUsers() {
        if( users.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("List is empty");
        }
        else
        {
            for (FacebookUser users : this.users)

            {
            System.out.println("Username: " + users.getUsername());
            }
        }
    }


    // adds a user

    public void addUser() {

        //creating an instance of FacebookUser class
        FacebookUser user1 = new FacebookUser();

        System.out.println("Enter username to add: ");
        String newUser = input.nextLine();
        user1.setUsername(newUser);
    // using the setter method in UserAccount to set the username for "fb" object


        //if statement checks if any object contains the same username  
        if (users.contains(user1)) { 
            System.out.println("Error, username already exists");

        } 
        else {

            System.out.println("Please enter password: ");
            String password = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter password hint: ");
            String passwordHint = input.nextLine();

            FacebookUser user2 = new FacebookUser();
            //creating another object for the "official" new user

            user2.setPassword(password);
            user2.setUsername(newUser);
            user2.setPasswordHint(passwordHint);

            users.add(user2);

            System.out.println(newUser + " has been added");

        }
    }

    // deletes a user
    public void deleteUser() {

    FacebookUser user1= new FacebookUser();
    System.out.println("Enter username you want to remove: ");
    String removeUser = input.nextLine();   


    user1.setUsername(removeUser);



        if (users.contains(user1)) {
            System.out.println("Enter password");
            String checkPassword = input.nextLine();
                    user1.setPassword(checkPassword);

            if (user1.password.equals(checkPassword)) {
                users.remove(user1);
                System.out.println(removeUser + " has been removed");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Incorrect password");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("User does not exist");

        }
    }
```

Comment: `private ArrayList<FacebookUser> users;` probably not going to work.  You need something like `Map<String,FacebookUser>` so you can map the user names to the name-password pairs.

Comment: An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help both us and you. Please edit the code in your question to the absolute minimum required to show the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not overriding the implementation of contains your code will not work. Try something similar to this .

```
    public void deleteUser() {

        FacebookUser user1= new FacebookUser();
        System.out.println("Enter username you want to remove: ");
        String removeUser = input.nextLine();  
        boolean isPresent = false; 
        for(FacebookUser user:users){
        if(user.getUsername.equals(removeUser)){
                isPresent = true;
            System.out.println("Enter Password");
            password = sc.nextLine();
            if(user.getPassword.equals(password)){
                users.remove(user);
                break;
            }else{
            System.out.println("Incorrect Password");
            }
        }
        }
        if(!isPresent){
        System.out.pritln("User does not exist");
        }
        }
```

Comment: Hi, one little problem the "User does not exist" prints out for each user in the array instead of just once

Comment: Hey sorry for that. Please put boolean isPresent = false; outside the for loop. This should solve your problem. I have edited the same in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, in `deleteUser()`, you are setting the user inputted password to `user1` before checking the password with `if (user1.password.equals(checkPassword))`. So, this `if` condition is always `true`.

I have commented that unnecessary line in below code.

(I assume you have overridden `equals()` method correctly in `FacebookUser` class. Because, `contains()` and `remove()` methods rely on `equals()` method.)

```
public void deleteUser() {

FacebookUser user1= new FacebookUser();
System.out.println("Enter username you want to remove: ");
String removeUser = input.nextLine();   


user1.setUsername(removeUser);



    if (users.contains(user1)) {
        System.out.println("Enter password");
        String checkPassword = input.nextLine();
                // I commented this line
                //user1.setPassword(checkPassword);

        if (user1.password.equals(checkPassword)) {
            users.remove(user1);
            System.out.println(removeUser + " has been removed");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Incorrect password");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("User does not exist");

    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried that and it is still not working with me

Comment: @BlemForeal, please post the code of `FacebookUser` class. As I've mentioned in my answer, you need to implement `equals()` method appropriately if you are using `contains()` and `remove()`.

Comment: Thank you for your time and help, I have found my solution with somebody else.

Comment: @BlemForeal, you are welcome. I will say this just for your information: I see that you have accepted the answer which use `if(user.getUsername.equals(removeUser))`. From software design perspective, overriding `equals()` and using `contains()` is better. It encapsulates the logic of comparing users to `FacebookUser` class.

Answer (score 0):

Try This.
When you are using user.contain(user1) it will compare all the fields of user 1 in user. ie it will check for a user having same username and password as user1. But the password is not set for this user 1 before. Hence, it will never find it in the list.

and when you use .remove() on arraylist, it takes index as argument. So always pass index of the user to be removed and not the user.

If still any error, post the error in the comment and I will let you know the solution.

```
public void deleteUser() {

    FacebookUser user1= new FacebookUser();
    System.out.println("Enter username you want to remove: ");
    String removeUser = input.nextLine();   

    int i=0;
    for(FacebookUser users:this.users)
    {
        boolean present = false;
        if(users.getUserName().equals(removeuser))
        {
            present = true;
            System.out.println("Enter password");
            String checkPassword = input.nextLine();
                    users.setPassword(checkPassword);
            if(users.getPassword().equals(checkPassword))
            {
                  this.users.remove(i);
                  System.out.println(removeUser + " has been removed");
                  break;
            }
            else
                System.out.println("Incorrect password");


        }
        i++;
    }
    if(!present)

        System.out.println("User does not exist");

}
```